# Selenium Java Invisibility of Child (nested) element

Tags: java, selenium

I know how to wait for element to disappear or appear (`invisibilityOfElementLocated` or `visibilityOfElementLocated`)
and also how to wait for child (nested) element to appear (`presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy`)

but i didn't find a way to wait for child (nested) element to disappear.

will appreciate your help!

Comment: Well, I'd say have a `child node xPath` (`or any locator`) and then use `Invisibility` for that web element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually very easy, this will make opposite to any of ExpectedConditions:

```
ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.CONDITION)
```